# MS Project integration help

Tags: ms-project, communication, remote-teams

My question is how to best integrate the MS Teams & Project Plan 5 for seamless project management and collaboration with my team?

First some background...

My organization has moved from using MS Project 2010 desktop to using the up-to-date MS Project in the 365 suite of products. To take advantage of the project management and collaboration, we've settled on using MS Teams and MS Project Plan 5 (which includes project for the web, project online and project desktop).

We have a SharePoint intranet which hosts general documentation, policies & procedures, calendars, that sort of stuff. We don't have any project management boards or such on there.

I've been using MS Teams to communicate task lists with my team, but I needed more functionality, so I began using MS Project Plan 5 in MS Teams to show tasks, buckets, timelines etc. This seemed to be a good first step, but ultimately this lacked a lot of functionality that MS Project 2010 desktop has. for example, in the MS Teams app I can't assign non-working times, and holidays, so when I create a Gantt chart, there is no automatic movement of dates considering for holidays.

I understand that what app is able to be integrated into MS Teams is actually 'MS Project for the web', which has less features.

if i look at project.microsoft.com, my projects created in the desktop app are not in the file list, and I'm not sure how I can sync from the desktop app to see the files in the list.

If i select 'Go To Project Online' i get the message below. I cant add or change this as I dont have permissions.
[image]

I downloaded the MS Project desktop app so I now have an up-to-date MS Project software rather than using the old 2010 version. In the file options I can share a project with SharePoint, but I don't have permissions for SharePoint, nor can I get it.

[image]

I'm finding the whole MS project integration cumbersome, and not what I want to happen happening. The resources available online are a little lacking in detail for the specific issues.

Has anyone run into the same issue & how have you implemented a solution that will allow you to project manage multiple projects, utilizing multiple people (on site and off site), and having a clear expectation of the tasks to be done?

Thanks.